# FastRTPS Topic & ROS2 Topic list

Tags: ros, ros2, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, All.

When using the HelloWorld example of the C++ example in ROS2, it appears in the node list, but not in the topic list.
Of course, when node_demos_cpp is used, it appears in the Topic list.

But I would like to use another DDS topic other than ROS2. (E. G., Using microRTPS, FastRTPS, etc.)
Is there anything I have to do separately?

Does not the topic list of ROS2 fetch the topic list registered in DDS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294882/fastrtps-topic-&-ros2-topic-list/) by [Kei](https://answers.ros.org/users/36003/kei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you please link to the example you are referring to or share the code. Otherwise it is unclear what are a referencing.

Yes, it is supposed to show all ROS 2 specific DDS topics. But it doesn't show all native DDS topics.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei](https://answers.ros.org/users/36003/kei/) on 2018-06-21**:
Thanks for your answer!

- [HelloWorld Example](https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-RTPS/blob/master/examples/C%2B%2B/HelloWorldExample/HelloWorld_main.cpp)

Can you tell me the difference between ROS2 specific DDS topics and native DDS topics?
Are the ROS2 specific DDS topics such as std_msgs in ROS2?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-06-21**:
The referenced example is not from ROS 2 but from FastRTPS - it doesn't contain any ROS specific code an won't appear in the ROS topic list. Please see http://design.ros2.org/articles/topic_and_service_names.html how ROS topic names are represented in DDS. Only those are reported by `ros2 topic`.

**Comment by [Kei](https://answers.ros.org/users/36003/kei/) on 2018-06-21**:
Oh, thank you!
The link you gave me was a great help :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just FYI, the `ros2 topic` command is not capable of this right now, but you can use ROS 2 to list all topics even the ones not formatted as ROS 2 topics. See the `Node.get_topic_names_and_types()` method in `rclpy` has a `no_demangle` option:

https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/blob/601d286cb5e049d930883f4e8fa21b58f2a46550/rclpy/rclpy/node.py#L290-L291

Here's a short Python script that should list all topics, even non-ROS 2 ones:

```
import rclpy
rclpy.init()
node = rclpy.create_node('list_all_topics_example')
print(node.get_topic_names_and_types(no_demangle=True))
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-06-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei](https://answers.ros.org/users/36003/kei/) on 2018-06-21**:
Cool! It can check native DDS topics!
It has really been a lot of help :)

Thanks!

**Comment by [mhallak](https://answers.ros.org/users/3537/mhallak/) on 2020-07-21**:
Super cool... Thank you for the script!